# How do I configure the load order of Rails engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, actionview

I have a Rails application that is using multiple gems. Each gem provides assets, that are added to the Rails asset path:

- main app
- admin engine with customised forms
- wysiwyg engine

I want to override some of the partials provided by the wysiwyg engine inside the admin engine. I know that I need to affect the order that each engine adds its asset paths to the ActionView lookup context used by `render` for partial resolution, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually documented by Rails but it took me a long time to find the relevant documentation. I assumed I needed to affect the bundler gem file load order, but I actually needed to define the order that engines (railties) are initialised:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Loading+priority

In my `config/application.rb` I added:

```
config.railties_order = [:main_app, Admin::Engine, :all]
```

I would prefer to define the dependency between the admin engine and the wysiwyg engine, but this does address my issue.